# NodeJs Express generate get request from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have a folder that has some json files in it, so I want to access them through my backend dynamically without the hassle to hard code changing data.

The Code works except one thing

```
localhost/Foo.json
Prints {Name:Bar} => expected Foo

localhost/Bar.json
Prints {Name:Bar} => expected Bar
```

so always the last entry in the data array is shown

```js
interface filesPath{
   name:string,
   ext:string, //here .json
   filepath:string,
}

var generateJson = (files:filesPath[]) => {
   var dataFiles = [];
   var dataNames = [];
   for(var x in files){
      dataFiles[x] = require(files[x].filepath);
      dataNames[x] = files[x].name;

      app.get('/'+dataNames[x]+files[x].ext,(req, res) => {
          res.json(dataFiles[x])  //Returns always last entry in array
      });
   }
}
```

Is there a simple fix?
Thanks in advance

Comment: When you're setting empty arrays into `dataFiles` and `dataNames` you're basically overriding existing values

Comment: Yes you are right but the problem still persists always the last value is read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've stumbled upon the concept of closures. What is happening is that the `x` you are passing to your function is not a copy of the value of `x` but the variable `x` itself (kind of like a pointer). This means all functions share the same variable thus one variable can only have one value.

The classical way to solve this is to pass `x` as an argument, thus breaking the closure:

```
for(var x in files){
  dataFiles[x] = require(files[x].filepath);
  dataNames[x] = files[x].name;

  app.get('/'+dataNames[x]+files[x].ext,((new_x) => (req, res) => {
      res.json(dataFiles[new_x])
  })(x)); // <-- pass in x here to become new_x
}
```

ES6 introduced the concept of `let` which does not create a closure. So a more modern solution is to simply use `let` instead of `var`:

```
for(let x in files){ // <-- this fixes it!!
  dataFiles[x] = require(files[x].filepath);
  dataNames[x] = files[x].name;

  app.get('/'+dataNames[x]+files[x].ext,(req, res) => {
      res.json(dataFiles[x])
  });
}
```